# How to share Trigger's result among multiple Zaps in Zapier?

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I have developed a Zapier Application which has a trigger. This trigger fetches unique contact information from a service. My intention is creating new subscriber or contact in Mailchimp, Mailer lite, Mad Mimi something like that via triggering new contact. It works well when I integrate it with any of them. But when I create different zaps for Mailchimp, Madmimi and Mailer lite using my Zapier application then the contact is saved in only single zaps. For example, Madmimi saves the contact but MailChimp and mailer lite does not receive or save the data. The Polling API of my Zapier application to trigger new contact is working fine. But why all Zaps can't receive the trigger simultaneously? No error or any type of exception found.
Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

All zaps should be able to see each new contact as they are all separate. Say we have 3 zaps that attach to mailchimp, madmimi, and mailer lite respectively.

Each zap polls the url for your app's "New Contact" trigger and keeps track of its own deduplication list (more info [here](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/deduplication/)). Since each zap is totally separate, none of them affect how often the other zaps get new info. Each of the 3 zaps has a polling period (meaning they only check for new data once every X minutes), so it's possible that you're not waiting long enough for all 3 to fire.

If this doesn't clear it up, I recommend writing into contact@zapier.com. We'll be able to look at your app and hopefully resolve your question.